# HMAC SHA-256 returns different value from JavaScript or PHP

Tags: c#, cryptography, hmac

I'm using a function to get the HMAC SHA-256 hash for a string value. But when I hashed the value in JavaScript and PHP, both languages computed the same hash, it was different from the C# outcome.

I've searched google and tried everything but it won't give me the correct outcome. Maybe I simply missed something.

```
    public static string ToHMAC(this string input, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

        var hasher = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        var data = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        return BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
    }
```

I tried making a little test in a console application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string input = "testpw1";
        const string token = "9e76fa355b5e4bed910f621f6a5fb971";
        var phash = input.ToSHA();
        Console.WriteLine("Hashed password: " + phash);
        Console.WriteLine("Signed password: " + phash.ToHMAC(token));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToSHA(this string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

        var hasher = new SHA256Managed();
        var data = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        return BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
    }

    public static string ToHMAC(this string input, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

        var hasher = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        var data = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        var retval = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();

        return retval;
    }
}
```

This is precisely how I do it in the MVC application. But somehow the values are the same as the PHP and JavaScript hashes. I really don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII` could be your problem – and if it is not, it will likely be in the future.

Comment: Yes, using ASCII is definitely a bad idea unless you absolutely *know* that all the data will be in ASCII. But even if that's currently the case, it would be really helpful if you could give us sample input and output.

Comment: That was not my original approach, it was one of those things I tried but didn't work. I originally used UTF-8. I changed it to UTF-8 again.

Comment: Have a look at the **bytes** of your test string.  Is there a UTF-8 BoM or not?  It isn't compulsory.  Are there end-of-lines in there?  They may differ between systems.  Basically look for invisible, byte-level differences between the two strings.